Problem to connect Intel API Fortran Compiler with Visual Studio 2022
For my work I am compiling Fortran code in Visual Studio. Since I updated Visual Studio to the latest version (17.9.6), I can't access my code anymore.
I already updated the Intel Base kit and HPC kit to the latest Version. During the Installation of the HPC kit I got a notification that the VS IDE could not be found. In some other forum they recommended to just skip the notification message, but when starting Visual Studio I could still not find the Fortran integration. Does anybody know how to solve the problem? My work depends on it :((

Welcome, please take the [tour] around this site. I also recommend top read [ask]. Did you try the steps suggested by the Documentation including following the Troubleshooting? Basically, they say to reinstall oneAPI.

Be aware that there is a dedicated support forum for oneAPI for Windows at the Intel site and you are more likely to find people answering directly from Intel there.

This reminds me of the VS2019 debacle with Intel Fortran 2022.1 that broke the integration. https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/VS-2022-v17-2-x-breaks-Intel-Fortran-use-v17-3-2-and-newer/m-p/1382358/highlight/true#M161212

Try repairing the installation of the Intel Fortran integration in Visual Studio through Control Panel > Programs and Features. If that doesn't work, uninstall and reinstall the integration using the latest version compatible with Visual Studio 17.9.6.
